# Padding and margin right 0, chrome shows otherwise

Tags: css

I have a content div within a main wrapper div. I've set both the `margin-right` and `paddding-right` to 0 on the content div, yet chrome still shows it extends to the end of the wrapper div, even passed it a little:

[image: div]

I'm trying to understand why this is. The Css for the outer and inner divs looks like this:

```
#Inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 3%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#outer {

    height:80vh;
    width:50vw;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:5%;
    border:3px solid black;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, 0);
    top:10%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #304352, #525252);
}
```

Is this just something to do with chrome or does the inner div really extend so far, even passed the wrapper?

Comment: that's not actually margin - though the coloration does imply it...what it is is empty space...because without a `float`, `display:inline-block`, etc. the div still restricts that space even though it's not "using" it, because block level elements are 100% width - setting the width property alone doesn't make that space available to other elements. Not the most technical explanation, but hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: That makes sense, thankyou. Do you have advice on which type of display I should try?

Comment: totally depends on what you're trying to achieve. if you want to have something else in that space on the right - you'll need to use either `display:inline-block` or `display:block` together with `float` for both objects.  If you don't need anything to fill that space, it really doesn't matter much what you set as the `display` for that div.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, I've found out that adding the `display` property of `inline-block` seemed to take away the right margin. I guess I still have more to understand about the block model.